# Extracting substring using nested for loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop, nested, substring

Hi i am given a text file A2Q2.txt. My program is suppose to read the file and only print 40 characters per line including spaces. After printing the 40 characters the program should start printing the other 40 characters on the second line and so on. Reading the file was easy but i am stuck as to how i can make it to print only 40 characters per line. My code is given below:

Here is a sample paragraph:

In ancient manuscripts, another means to divide sentences in into paragraphs was a line break (newline) followed by an initial at the beginning of the next paragraph. An initial is an oversize capital letter, sometimes outdented beyond the margin of text. This style can be seen, for example, in the original Old English manuscript of Beowulf. Outdenting is still used in English typography, though not commonly.[4] Modern English typography usually indicates a new paragraph by indenting the first line. This style can be seen in the (handwritten) United States Constitution from 1787. For additional ornamentation, a hedera leaf or other symbol can be added to the inter-paragraph whitespace, or put in the indentation space.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class A2Q2 {
    public static final int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 40;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printFile();
    }

    public static void printFile() {
        BufferedReader fileIn;
        FileReader fileReaderIn;
        String word;
        String inputLine;

        try {
            fileReaderIn = new FileReader("A2Q2in.txt");
            fileIn = new BufferedReader(fileReaderIn);
            inputLine =fileIn.readLine();

            while (inputLine != null) {
                System.out.print(inputLine + " ");
                inputLine = fileIn.readLine();  
            }
            fileIn.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at [substring](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm)?

Comment: In this line, System.out.print(inputLine + " "); try this: System.out.print(inputLine.substring(0,40)); to see what happens.

Comment: Its giving an error message saying String index out or range: 40

Comment: Check the length before printing. Make use of StringBuilder inside while loop. Use delete, append, length method to solve your purpose.

Comment: Hi @AbhashUpadhyaya, i am sorry but i am relatively new to Java. I have done python before. I would really appreciate if you could elaborate on your comment more? How should i approach it?

Comment: @Mark Peters, can you clarify what should be done in a case where a line read from file contains less than 40 chars? Is it mandatory to have 40 characters per line?

Comment: @MarkPeters, Were you able to do it? Sorry, I was away so couldn't help much.

Comment: @AbhashUpadhyaya, I have not been able to figure a way around it. In case there are less then 40 characters that would probably be the end of the paragraph?

Comment: @MarkPeters, Can you please provide a sample input & required output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below solution. It reads the paragraph line by line and then work on each line such that it inserts a new line character at 40th index from 0 or the last new line character inserted. Also, instead of performing manipulation on each line, it can be done on whole paragraph by first appending it in the builder object and performing the insertion but it may be bad for file containing lot of data.
Since you have not mentioned anything about file containing multiple paragraphs, below solution works best for a single paragraph.

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class A2Q2 {

    public static final int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 40;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printFile();
    }

    public static void printFile() {

        BufferedReader fileIn = null;
        FileReader fileReaderIn = null;
        String inputLine;
        int lengthOfLine;
        int newLineCount;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

        try {
            fileReaderIn = new FileReader("A2Q2in.txt");
            fileIn = new BufferedReader(fileReaderIn);

            // read paragraph line by line
            while ((inputLine = fileIn.readLine()) != null) {

                // counter for iteration, set on each iteration for new line from paragraph 
                int ctr = 0;
                // append line to string builder object
                sb.append(inputLine);
                lengthOfLine = sb.length();

                // identifies how many newline characters to be added in the line
                newLineCount = lengthOfLine / MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE;

                // if newCount > 0 is true, signifies that line needs to be broken to 40 chars
                if(newLineCount > 0) {

                    while(ctr < newLineCount) {
                        // insert newline character at 40th index from last newline character 
                        sb.insert((MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE+(MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE*ctr)+ctr), "\n");
                        ctr++;
                    }
                    System.out.print(sb.substring(0, (MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE*newLineCount)+ctr));

                    // delete the printed string and keeping the left over to be appended by next line 
                    sb.delete(0, ((MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE*newLineCount)+ctr));
                }
            }
            // print the remaining string left in the builder object.
            System.out.print(sb.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        finally {

            if(fileIn != null) {
                try {
                    fileIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(fileReaderIn != null) {
                try {
                    fileReaderIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The input for the above code is:

```
In ancient manuscripts, another means to divide sentences in into paragraphs was a line break 
followed by an initial at the beginning of the next paragraph. An initial is an oversize capital 
letter, sometimes outdented beyond the margin of text. This style can be seen, for example, in 
the original Old English manuscript of Beowulf. Outdenting is still used in English typography, 
though not commonly.[4] Modern English typography usually indicates a new paragraph by indenting 
the first line. This style can be seen in the (handwritten) United States Constitution from 1787. 
For additional ornamentation, a hedera leaf or other symbol can be added to the inter-paragraph 
whitespace, or put in the indentation space.
```

---

And the output based on assumptions(because of lack of requirements) is:

```
In ancient manuscripts, another means to
 divide sentences in into paragraphs was
 a line break followed by an initial at 
the beginning of the next paragraph. An 
initial is an oversize capital letter, s
ometimes outdented beyond the margin of 
text. This style can be seen, for exampl
e, in the original Old English manuscrip
t of Beowulf. Outdenting is still used i
n English typography, though not commonl
y.[4] Modern English typography usually 
indicates a new paragraph by indenting t
he first line. This style can be seen in
 the (handwritten) United States Constit
ution from 1787. For additional ornament
ation, a hedera leaf or other symbol can
 be added to the inter-paragraph whitesp
ace, or put in the indentation space.
```

Each line is of exactly 40 chars.